# how to fix a "no entries found error" when building for production with parcel bundler?

Tags: html, build, netlify, parcel

```
Server running at http://localhost:1234 
×  No entries found.
    at Bundler.bundle (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\Bundler.js:275:17)
    at async Bundler.serve (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\Bundler.js:842:7)
    at async Command.bundle (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\cli.js:224:20)
```

parcel-build and server rendering was working just fine until i tried hosting my project via netlify, the site couldn't be deployed by netlify and their Docs suggest to ensure the site is deploying just fine locally, going back to VSCode i tried rendering the page via the terminal using "parcel index.html", the site deploys just fine but when i try "parcel build" above is the error am getting, please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like your development server runs fine but the build command fails. Do you have `package.json` in your project? If so, have you installed the dependencies by `npm install`? If so, have you tried completely removing the `node_modules` folder and reinstalling it?